# SSAS: cell data security for multiple measures

Tags: security, ssas, mdx

I have multiple measures, i want to restrict each individual measure.

department  measure1 measure2 measure3
    A          NULL     1       NULL
    B          1        1        1
    C          NULL     1       NULL

can i do this with cell data restrictions?

essential this is a combination of roles
Role 1 - only give access to measure2
Role 2 - only allow department B to see all measure
Role 3 - would be the intersect of both

Answer (score 1):

**Role 1**:
The SSAS Role setting actually allows you to set restrictions based on ***Measurement*** in the `Dimensional Data` page. so unselect all others and only leave "**measure2**" for users in "**Role1**" to read.

**Role 2**:
Similarly, go to the `Dimensional Data` page, zoom into the *department* dimension, select only the "department B".

**Role 3**:
Repeat the above settings together in the `Dimensional Data` page of "**Role3**".

And keep in mind, SSAS Access is additive, means if there is any user existing in both "**Role1**" or "**Role2**", basically there is no restriction for it at all.

Comment: a caveat is a bunch of the measures is calculated measures therefore the restrictions cant be set using dimensional security.  i was debating user the cell data restrictions in order limit the data. one question is using the ancestor function to limit the department hierarchy. the question is what would be MDX script for parent-child hierarchy?

Comment: @AL, if you would like to use ```Cell Data``` to restrict measurement access, the **MDX** code would look like this:```Measures.CurrentMember IS [Measures].[<Your Measurement>]```